# $X_n$ Poisson of parameter $\lambda_n \to +\infty$ tends to $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\lambda_n \in \mathbb R^+$ with $\lambda_n \to +\infty$. Let $X_n$ a sequence of random variables with distribution Poisson with parameter $\lambda_n$. Show that $$\frac{X_n-\lambda_n}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}$$ tends to a Standard Normal distribution.

**Attempt:** $F_n(t) =\mathbb P(X_n \leq (t+\lambda_n{\sqrt{\lambda_n}})) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (t+\lambda_n{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}) \rfloor} e^{-\lambda_n}\frac{\lambda_n^k}{k!}$

and I would like to take $n \to \infty$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the characteristic function instead. Start from the fact that $X_n$ has characteristic function $$\phi_n(t)=\exp(\lambda_n (e^{it}-1))$$ so the ratio has characteristic function

$$\psi_n(t)=\exp(\lambda_n (e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda_n}}-1))e^{-it\sqrt{\lambda_n}}$$
Taylor expansion gives:

$$\psi_n(t)=\exp\left[\lambda_n\left(\frac{it}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}-\frac{t^2}{2\lambda_n}+O(\lambda_n^{-3/2})\right)-it\sqrt{\lambda_n}\right]\to\exp(-t^2/2)$$

which is precisely the characteristic function of a standard normal.

Comment: Umh. Poisson is a discrete random variable, what does it mean its characteristic function?

Comment: Ok ok I solved it, it's just a sum.

Comment: @Maffred Yes it can be represented as a sum (which evaluates to a closed form given in the answer). CF is defined as $\phi(t)= E(e^{itX}).$ No assumptions about the distribution of $X.$ Formulas for calculating expected value are where the assumptions enter.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $X_n \sim Poiss(\lambda_n)$ can be expressed as 
$$
X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim Poiss(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i = \lambda_n),
$$
namely, $X_n$ is basically a sum of $n$ Poisson i.i.d. ($X_i$)  where each $\lambda_i = \lambda_n/n$. Moreover, $\operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \lambda_n/n $, thus $S_n^2 = \lambda_n$ and $S_n = \sqrt{\lambda_n}$. Define, 
$$
Y_i = X_i - \lambda_n/n,
$$
therefore, 
$\mathbb{E}Y_i = 0$, $\forall i$, and $T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i  = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \lambda_n = X_n - \lambda_n$. Hence, as $\operatorname{Var}(Y_n) =\lambda_n$, then by the Lyapunov CLT (given that the sequence satisfies Lyapunov condition, namely, $\exists \delta >0$, $\sum\mathbb{E}|Y_i|^{2+\delta}/S_n^{2+\delta} \to 0$) we have that
$$
Z_n = \frac{Y_n}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}} \xrightarrow{D} \mathcal{N}(0,1).
$$

Comment: $\lambda_n/n$ depends on $n$, so usual CLT is not applicable for this case.

Comment: @Nch - Thank you. WLOG, If I take $\lambda = 1/100$ for $n=100$, and furthermore I left with $\lambda = 1/100$, then it seems to make it right. What do you think?

Comment: Sure. But the initial problem was to find limit distribution for $\frac{X_n-\lambda_n}{\sqrt{\lambda_n}}\neq \frac{S_n-0.01n}{\sqrt{0.01n}}$, where $S_n$ is the sum of i.i.d. Poisson r.v.'s with $\lambda=0.01$. 
The situation when for any $n$ you have $n$ i.i.d.r.v.'s whose distributions vary with $n$ differs from the classical case where the summands are i.i.d. and increasing $n$ does not affect on the first summands.

Comment: @Nch - I see. Thank you. Before I delete the answer, is there a decent way to apply a modified CLT for the original problem?

Comment: Here one can apply some CLT in Lindeberg or Lyapounov conditions for series $X_{n,1},\ldots,X_{n,n}$ of i.i.d.r.v.'s for any $n$. For example, look here: https://www.stat.washington.edu/fritz/DATAFILES394_2011/CLT.pdf

Comment: @Nch - Thank you. However, I wasn't sure hoe to verify rigorously the Lyapunov condition in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see no reason to do this, because with the help of characteristic functions the proof is simple and direct.